# Secure my web service from being called without an active Facebook session

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a Facebook canvas app (it's a flash app), all Facebook calls are done from the client (JS SDK), I have set up a php web service on my server to store and read data from my data base, so basically at the moment I'm not using the Facebook php sdk at all.

What would be the simplest way to secure my web service from being called without an active Facebook session?

---

**UPDATE:** Worked it out, Paul's answer is correct, thanks @Paul.

The issue was simple: initializing the JS sdk is done AFTER php session started so further calls to my php files were not recognized as logged in. In order for it to work I initialized the Facebook session in the file that embeds the swf (was Html, now it's php), this means that handling users that did not yet authorized the application is done via php, before the swf is even loaded.
Now I can rely on active session and user identification in my web service, coffee tastes much better now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a really good way to do this without checking that the FB access token is valid.

If I were you, I'd use the SDK to validate the sessions. It's super easy to use just grab it from [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) and try the following code:

```
<?php
require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    // you have a secure session
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I was trying just this... however, $facebook->getUser() always returns 0 - as no active session (I do have a Facebook application instance cause I can get the app access_token) - any ideas?

Comment: has the user definitely logged in to facebook and authorised your application? They would have had to follow the flow on this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: Yes, the user is logged in and authorized the app. 
However, the user is not supposed to load this "page" directly, it is a "web service" for the flash - to save and load data, it returns JSON objects. Basically if it is called by flash (and in the future a mobile app) it is a "safe" call by a logged in user. And this is exactly the issue - How can I restrict access to this "web service" to only users that are currently logged in to my Facebook app?